# Robocopy command isn't backing up, is this command valid?

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, batch-file, robocopy

I'm trying to use Robocopy to incrementally back-up my project every 15 minutes, only if there are changes. I'm using Windows Task Scheduler to start the .bat file at start-up, and because I don't often run my computer I started the script immediately.

Since I don't want the command prompt to display every 15 minutes, I set the flags to not output the log. Because of this I'm unsure if it's actually running, and can't see the file name in my task manager.

The first time I started it without the no log flags, it backed up to my folder as expected. Since then there have been no incremental back-ups despite working on my project and saving constantly throughout the day using auto-save with VS Code.

Is it closing immediately because I'm not outputting the log and is this normal, or did I make an error in the syntax? Should there have been multiple folders or did I miss a flag to do what I'm trying to do?

```
robocopy C:\Users\July\Desktop\TestFolder D:\TestFolder/s /xo /z /np /b /mot:15 /mt:4 /nfl /ndl/ njh/ njs > log:nul /xd D:\TestFolder\.git D:\Psyche\.tmp.drivedownload
```

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe this:

```
robocopy "C:\Users\July\Desktop\TestFolder" "D:\TestFolder" /s /xo /z /np /b /mot:15 /mt:4 /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /xd "D:\TestFolder\.git" "D:\Psyche\.tmp.drivedownload" > nul
```

Comment: Thank you, when I open the file it keeps the command prompt open. Is there anyway to run it in the background? Also do you know if the xd command is supposed to define the source directory to exclude or the target direction not to write to? Or does it not matter? The documentation all just says to exclude the directions.

Comment: If you define the option: "Run if user is connected or not" or if you run the task under another user in task schuedler there shouldn't be displayed a command prompt during the process. The XD switch excludes on both sides since it is mirroring (the source will not be deleted of course)

Comment: Thank you very much, though I'm running this script now and noticed it's still not incremental. It copies the folder over and updates the changes, but it overwrites the old files instead of incrementally making new back-ups.

Comment: I'm afraid robocopy doesn't make the type of backup you are talking about. When you make a new backup by default it only backups: File that don't exist in the destination, Files that are different, it doesn't copy files that are  the same in source and destination. You are right it overwrites the old files.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the information. I thought that was the case when I was researching it, but someone suggested it to me because I wasn't happy with Duplicity for doing incremental back-ups. Thanks for confirming that.